# Extract nested object of an object collection (products of location)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, rails-geocoder

I have two models : `Product` and `Location`.

```rb
class Location
  has_many :products
end

class Product
  belongs_to :location
end
```

When I use the geocoder gem, I can use a near scope, that allow me to select every location around a specific address. Something like :

```rb
@locations_near_paris = Location.near("Paris")
```

Now, I want to make a collection of products, that are close from Paris, using the @locations_near_paris collection. How can I do that ?

I did the following, but I feel it's not a good practice...

```rb
close_locations.each do |l|
  unless l.products.nil?
    l.products.each do |p|
      close_products << p
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the geocoder method returns an AR, but let's assume it does not.

```
location_ids = Location.near("Paris").collect do |location|
  location.id
end

paris_products = Product.where(location_id: location_ids)
```

Comment: Ok it works too, but do you know if it is efficient with the database requests ?

Comment: It should be efficient. Especially if you have added an index to your location_id column in your products table.

Comment: Try the code in the Rails console and check how many queries are being performed. I would assume it would be two queries.

Comment: Thanks ! And how can I keep the collection distance ordered ?